# Rust - value of type cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<>`

Tags: rust

I have struct from which I want to extract the data.

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct RunResult {
    pub runs: Vec<RunDetails>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct RunDetails {
    pub details: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub id: String,
    pub type: String,
}
```

I am getting the data which got inserted in above struct in the variable `result` which I am iterating below

```
let my_result:RunResult = result
        .runs
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|line| line.details.contains(&"foo"))
        .collect();
```

I am getting the error as

```
value of type `RunResult` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=RunDetails>`
```

I want to get the record where `type=OK`, `details contains foo` with highest `id`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for `collect` [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

Your struct `RunResult` should implement [`FromIterator<RunDetails>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html).

Try adding this (untested by me):

```rust
impl FromIterator<RunDetails> for RunResult {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item=RunDetails>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        Self {
            runs: Vec::from_iter(iter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting the error as ```a trait with a similar name exists: `IntoIterator````

Comment: FWIW, it's more efficient to delegate to `Vec`'s `IntoIterator` implementation than to iterate manually.

Comment: @SolomonUcko, may you please tell or link to this? Thank you.

Comment: @Mikeumus I think I meant FromIterator: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E